# Setting up git on wordpress: Issue with git add

Tags: wordpress, git, bitbucket

I have been trying to setup git on a WordPress site, The issue seems to be that while I run `git add --all`.

The files get deleted for some reason. Not sure what seems to be the issue.

Comment: What is the real issue you're facing to ? The files are deleted **when** you run `git add --all` ? Can you show us the result of `git status` after typing the `git add --all` command ?

Comment: So while I run git status after git add --all, i get two blocks of logs one where it lists all the files as created and other where it lists all files as delete. I cannot replicate the issue now since it deletes the files and site goes offline.

The issue occurs with one specific server. I ran the same routine of setting up in another WordPress server and there was no issue.

Comment: If it helps I got "There are too many unreachable loose objects; run 'git prune' to remove them." while I ran git pull on the server where I have come across the issue.

Comment: Are you using gitlab ? If yes, which version ?

Comment: No, I am not using gitlab.